# Installing NPM package globally does not create bash command

Tags: node.js, npm

I've tried to install `http-server`. It installs fine. Here's the output:

```
$ npm install -g http-server
/Users/jonrojas/.npm-packages/bin/http-server -> /Users/jonrojas/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
/Users/jonrojas/.npm-packages/bin/hs -> /Users/jonrojas/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
/Users/jonrojas/.npm-packages/lib
└── http-server@0.9.0
```

As soon as I try to run `hs`, I get:

```
-bash: hs: command not found
```

When I try `npm config get prefix`, I receive:

```
/Users/jonrojas/.npm-packages
```

How would I update my .bashrc file to get this working? (or other steps?)

To note: this isn't specific to `http-server`. I also tried to install another package that has a bash command, but it also did not work.

Comment: I'm guessing something like `export PATH="$(npm bin):$PATH"` would do the trick. See [`npm bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/bin).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jordan.

npm bin: 

  `/Users/jonrojas/node_modules/.bin`

To my .bachrc file, I've added:

  `export PATH="/Users/jonrojas/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"`

running `hs` still gives me:

  `-bash: hs: command not found`

Comment: Did you `source ~/.bashrc` so that line actually gets executed? And does a symlink called `hs` exist in that directory?

Comment: I did `source ~/.bashrc`, but I'm not positive about the symlink. Will check into that. I noticed when I `ls /Users/jonrojas/node_modules/` I get an error: `ls: /Users/jonrojas/node_modules/: No such file or directory`. It's definitely weird as `npm bin` returns `/Users/jonrojas/node_modules/.bin`

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like there's something weird going on with your Node or npm install.

Comment: try running `npm link`

Comment: Try reinstalling node & npm.